# Why is my server with memory pressure when I have 4.3GB available memory?

Tags: sql-server, memory, troubleshooting

I'm doing a couple of tests in my local computer and I noticed that the plan cache was being wiped every couple of minutes.
After researching a bit I noticed on my error log that my instance was with memory pressure and paging out... 
I really can't understand what's going on as I do have my perfmon open all the time and I do have 4.3GB available memory and the instance is not caped in memory limit.

Do you guys have any idea what's going on? 
I also would like to take this opportunity to ask if anyone knows a way to catch when does the lazy writer gets executed ?Is there any way to track him down ?

Thank you all!
@@Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
sys.dm_os_ring_buffers

```
<Record id = "101241" type ="RING_BUFFER_RESOURCE_MONITOR" time ="4419025954">
<ResourceMonitor>
    <Notification>RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW</Notification>
    <IndicatorsProcess>2</IndicatorsProcess>
    <IndicatorsSystem>2</IndicatorsSystem>
    <IndicatorsPool>2</IndicatorsPool>
    <NodeId>0</NodeId>
    <Effect type="APPLY_LOWPM" state="EFFECT_ON" reversed="1">1114779</Effect>
    <Effect type="APPLY_HIGHPM" state="EFFECT_OFF" reversed="0">0</Effect>
    <Effect type="REVERT_HIGHPM" state="EFFECT_ON" reversed="1">791590828</Effect>
</ResourceMonitor>
<MemoryNode id="0">
    <TargetMemory>388744</TargetMemory>
    <ReservedMemory>34086804</ReservedMemory>
    <CommittedMemory>388740</CommittedMemory>
    <SharedMemory>0</SharedMemory>
    <AWEMemory>0</AWEMemory>
    <PagesMemory>151288</PagesMemory>
</MemoryNode>
<MemoryRecord>
    <MemoryUtilization>48</MemoryUtilization>
    <TotalPhysicalMemory>16664584</TotalPhysicalMemory>
    <AvailablePhysicalMemory>4534516</AvailablePhysicalMemory>
    <TotalPageFile>30857376</TotalPageFile>
    <AvailablePageFile>8330020</AvailablePageFile>
    <TotalVirtualAddressSpace>137438953344</TotalVirtualAddressSpace>
    <AvailableVirtualAddressSpace>137404308856</AvailableVirtualAddressSpace>
    <AvailableExtendedVirtualAddressSpace>0</AvailableExtendedVirtualAddressSpace>
</MemoryRecord>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is max server memory set to? What is your total database size? What else is consuming memory on this machine?

Comment: Your SQL server is victim of paging this is not actually SQL Server fault but windows is paging out SQL Server process to disk because windows is facing memory pressure. You said you have not restricted memory for SQL server I suggest do it ASAP. Leave *enough* memory for OS to perform. Mean while  [This SE thread](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138003/troubleshooting-memory-pressure-how-to-avoid-paging-out-sql-server/138010#138010) would help you understand the problem. You can avoid this problem by providing Locked pages in memory privilege to SQL Server service account

Comment: Well , this is my local instance with only 10dbs and no users/processes connected at all. The only db that is getting hit a lot of times is my SQLSentry DB but anyway, if the instance is not memory caped and the OS says that I have more than 4gb memory free, why am I having memory issues ? The database where my plan is disappearing is 12MB size .

@AaronBertrand , shouldn't I be seeing my memory hitting 99% if I was under memory pressure ??

Thank you guys!

Comment: Number of databases is largely irrelevant, and I'm not talking about what else is running within SQL Server, but on the machine in general.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to describe everything that's running on this machine as this is a Desktop user machine so loads of apps are running here so all sort of apsp are currently running... What I don't get is why is this happening when the task manager shows me 25% of memory free. Isn't this enough? Why am I not hitting 99% of memory used then? Thanks!

Comment: Wait .. *this is a Desktop user machine..* and you are running SQL Server on this machine which is running *loads of apps are running here so all sort of apsp are currently running*? Is the database set to `auto close`?

Comment: No, none of the dbs are set to auto close. 
Yap, this is my working machine and while I was debugging something else I noticed that the plans were being wiped so I found that I was under memory pressure but the task manager doesn't show me that so that's why I decided to get extra help. Thank you.

Comment: [Stop looking at task manager](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/why-is-sql-server-memory-showing-in-task-manager). And don't expect SQL Server to play nicely with "all sorts of apps"...

Comment: You really need to cap the memory.